# The index of some perturbation about elliptic operator with Robin boundary condition

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $I$ be an closed interval $[0, 1]$. $C^{2}(\bar{I})$ is the space of all $C^{2}$ functions on $(0, 1)$  with continuity at boundary and usual maximal norm. $C(\bar{I})$ is the space of all continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ with maximal norm. For $u\in C^{2}(\bar{I})$,  define two operators
  $$ Au = \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}u + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}u \quad (1) $$ 
And 
    $$ Bu= \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}u \quad (2)$$
Let $L$ be a closed operator from $C^{2}(\bar{I})$  into $C(\bar{I})$ such that 
         $$
            Lu(x) = f(x)\\
               \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0)=0, \quad u(1)=0  \quad (3)
$$
where $f\in C(\bar{I})$. 
Define $L_{0}$ from $C^{2}(\bar{I})$ into $C(\bar{I})$ as 
    $$ L_{0}u=(   \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0), u(1))$$
From (3) we can view $ (L, L_{0})$ as a linear map from  Banach space $C^{2}(\bar{I})$ into Banach space $C(\bar{I})\bigoplus R \bigoplus R$ with usual norm. According to classic elliptic theory, when $L=A$, we can claim that $(A, L_{0})$ is an algebraic and topological isomorphic from  $C^{2}(\bar{I})$ into Banach space $C(\bar{I})\bigoplus R \bigoplus R$. Therefor 
     $$
      index(A, L_{0})=0
     $$
From (2), we can view $(B, 0)$ as a compact operator from $C^{2}(\bar{I})$ into Banach space $C(\bar{I})\bigoplus R \bigoplus R$. Therefore according to Theorem 5.26 in  Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators (Classics in Mathematics, springer 1995)
by Tosio Kato, we have 
     $$ 
     index (A-B, L_{0}) = index(A, L_{0}) = 0
     $$
There is a contraction since $A-B$ is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ which says that 
    $$
       index(A-B, L_{0})=-1
    $$
 Where am I wrong? Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator $B$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you. I mistook that $(B, 0)$ is compact.